# Include a game's name in question titles to avoid confusion in the HNQ sidebar

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, hot-network-questions

I just joined this exchange solely in order to post this meta question. Usually, I hang out in the programming-related exchanges, but, as with any old dictionary, one gets ... sidetracked ... by the interesting questions in the sidebar.

I've noticed that the gaming questions make next to no sense at all *unless* you know what game is being discussed; for instance [What is a lane?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258937/what-is-a-lane).

I was just thinking, if the title would include the name of the game, that would clear things up *immensely*, and avoid people having to open the question just to understand the title (unless that's actually your intention...).

Answer (score 3):

We have tags for this. These are included in the `<title>` of the page, and hence show up in Google search results.

The linked question is tagged [moba](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moba), since it applies to those games.

Comment: You are quite right, but this information does _not_ shop up in the "Hot Network Questions" list in the sidebar. _That's_ where I'd like to see it, not in Google searches.

Comment: @KlaymenDK & fredley, there's also precedent to edit the game title into the question if [the title is ambiguous without it](//meta.arqade.com/q/6950/28182)